# Creating list-view dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm creating dynamically a list view. I'm able to create the list view dynamically but I even want to dynamically build and then append

HTML code

```
<ul id="menu" data-role="listview">
</ul>
```

jQuery code

```
$("#my_menu").append('<li><a class="button" href="#"><img src="menu.png" >'+ this.textContent + '  </a> </li>')
```

My List View is not automatically refreshed?

Comment: And...What is your question?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: $('#my_menu').listview('refresh');

Comment: Maybe jQuery doesn't like that your `img` tag is not properly closed? (Should be self closing `<img src="..." />`)

Comment: When does the jQuery code run? In what context?

Comment: When do you want to update the list? At that scenario use an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rename the class "button", this may irritate JQM, here's my proposal, I think theres a missing semicolon at the end btw. Is the link to the IMG working? you may also try 'images/my-button.png' ...

```
$('#my_menu').append(' <li><a href="#" class="zclass123"><img src="menu.png"> '
                       + this.textContent 
                       + ' </a></li> ');

$('#my_menu'').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: The semi-colon is optional, the original is perfectly valid, see http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.9